# Seaborn plot goes blank when adding legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I just started with a tutorial on Seaborn from a book; 'Python Data Science Handbook'. When I execute the part about adding a legend to the plot, the plot figures goes blank.

I entered these lines of code one by one in my Spyder console

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 500)
y = np.cumsum(rng.randn(500, 6), 0)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

[image: Plot after executing previous line]

Then followed by

```
plt.legend('ABCDEF', ncol=2, loc='upper left');
```

[image]

Can't understand why the plot figure goes blank. And I have the latest version of Seaborn installed.

Comment: try increasing `ncol`. ie, `plt.legend('ABCDEF', ncol=20, loc='upper left')`

Comment: @VanPeer, thanks for clarifying that. After going over the example again in the book, the author did execute both lines at the same time. It was really a quick glance at the page and I assume both lines were executed separately. Odd why developers would structure the code this way.

Comment: where are you using seaborn here? Also, I used your code exactly as you put it (except for the imports) and I got the legend in the plot ok.

Comment: @nahusznaj, as mentioned, I entered plot.plot(x,)

Comment: @nahusznaj, as mentioned in my post it was entered in my Spyder IDE console. I entered the line .. plot.plot(x,y) followed by the enter buttoning in my console, and then entered the plt.legend ... line of code separately and pressed the enter button This was the the error. After entering both lines of code together separated with \n, I was able to generate the plot. I did not include the two lines related to import as those import lines are needed as a minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run code together:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 500)
y = np.cumsum(rng.randn(500, 6), 0)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.legend('ABCDEF', ncol=2, loc='upper left');
```

this results:

[image]

but fi we run first just plotting and on separate cell legend, we will get:

[image]

because `plt.legend` by itself tries to create legend on empty fig that has no data

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Mr. Bukhari.